# Flutter auto_route import as prefix not generated well

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have a class page route AppointmentCreatePage which required a parameter from a class model , but I define this import model as a prefix

AppointmentCreatePage class

```
import 'package:project_mobile/features/brand/model/brand_response_model.dart'
as model_brand;

class AppointmentCreatePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppointmentCreatePage({Key? key, this.brandData}) : super(key: key);

  final model_brand.Data? brandData; <--- use import as prefix

  @override
  State<AppointmentCreatePage> createState() => _AppointmentCreatePageState();
}
```

and the generated file (router.gr.dart)

```
/// generated route for
/// [AppointmentCreatePage]
class AppointmentCreateRoute extends PageRouteInfo<AppointmentCreateRouteArgs> {
  AppointmentCreateRoute({
    Key? key,

    Data? brandData, <--- Error Undefined class 'Data'

  }) : super(
    AppointmentCreateRoute.name,
    path: '/appointment-create-page',
    args: AppointmentCreateRouteArgs(
     key: key, 
     brandData: brandData,
    ),
   );

  static const String name = 'AppointmentCreateRoute';
}

class AppointmentCreateRouteArgs {
  const AppointmentCreateRouteArgs({
    this.key,        
    this.brandData,
  });

  final Key? key;

  final Data? brandData; <--- Error Undefined class 'Data'

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'AppointmentCreateRouteArgs{key: $key, brandData: $brandData}';
  }
}
```

what I expect is `final Data? brandData;` on(router.gr.dart) can be generated same as like on the AppointmentCreatePage class `final model_brand.Data? brandData` and on the router.dart can automatically import this class model

`router.dart`

```
import 'package:project_mobile/features/brand/model/brand_response_model.dart' 
as model_brand; <--- expect can be imported automatically

part 'router.gr.dart';

@MaterialAutoRouter(              
  replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route',
  preferRelativeImports: true,
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    AutoRoute(
      page: SplashPage,
      initial: true,
    ),
    AutoRoute(page: OnBoardingPage),
    AutoRoute(page: TabShowCasePage),
    AutoRoute(page: LoginPage),
    AutoRoute(page: ForgotPasswordPage),
    AutoRoute(page: VerificationPage),
    AutoRoute(page: RegisterPage),
    AutoRoute(page: AppointmentCreatePage),
    
  ],              
)

class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter{}
```